# Uncaught Error: getSessionData requires two non-null arguments JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webview, salesforce, chromium

I am loading `JavaScript` file in `Webview` in `android` device. While loading file, I am not getting content on `webview`, it just shows empty and in logs getting error

```
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught Error: getSessionData requires two non-null arguments (domain, keys).", source: https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/frame/session.esw.min.js (2)
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "No domain set!", source: https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/eswFrame.min.js (5)
The thread 0x1d has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #29
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7
The thread 0x7 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #31
The thread 0x1f has exited with code 0 (0x0).
[Choreographer] Skipped 1299 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: initESW is not defined", source: https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.html (1)
```

ulr in above error, is not the exact url being reguested, below is the correct ulr

```
https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js
```

Below file I am using

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="Chat1()">Submit</button>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function Chat1() {
        var initESW = function (gslbBaseURL) {
        embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = true; //Or false
        embedded_svc.settings.language = ''; //For example, enter 'en' or 'en-US'
        embedded_svc.settings.enabledFeatures = ['LiveAgent'];
        embedded_svc.settings.entryFeature = 'LiveAgent';
        embedded_svc.init(
            'https://ulr.my.salesforce.com',
            'https://ulr.force.com/visualforce',
            gslbBaseURL,
            '00D7a00000055uj',
            'Products',
            {
                'baseLiveAgentContentURL': 'https://c.la3-c1cs-cdg.salesforceliveagent.com/content',
                'deploymentId': '720008Oqg',
                'buttonId': '5730PID',
                'baseLiveAgentURL': 'https://d.la3-c1cs-cdg.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',
                'eswLiveAgentDevName': 'EmbeddedServiceLiveAgent_Parent0000000jLUAQ_17d9a605e8e',
                'isOfflineSupportEnabled': false
            }
        );
    };
    if (!window.embedded_svc) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        var jsUlr1 = 'https://ulr.salesforce.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js/'
        console.log("Control here2")
        s.src = jsUlr1;
        s.onload = function () {
            initESW(null);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
    else {
        initESW('https://service.force.com');
    }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can get more information [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71478674/unable-to-open-asset-url-file-android-asset-www-sf-min-js-xamarin-forms) regarding what I am doing. In this link ulr not being used, using local file.

I want to know how to fix `getSessionData requires two non-null arguments` ? this is really painful error .

This error we can see on this url

```
https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/frame/session.esw.min.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce attempts to parse the URL of your webview in order to extract a domain.
The domain is then passed to multiple function calls, including getSessionData.
You can open the non-minified https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/eswFrame.js file and notice this block:

```js
window.location.search.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=([\S]+)/g, function(match, key, value) {
  if(key === "parent") {
    // Only take the parts between the first instance of // and the / following it.
    this.parentOrigin = value;
  }
}.bind(this));
```

This function is unable to parse a domain from a local file loaded with `file:///`, which is what you do when you load the webview. Thus the errors.

The solution is to host a local server within your app or to store your webview script on a remote server so Salesforce can properly parse the domain from the webview url.

For instance, loading the following script using a `http://localhost` URL displays the chat agent properly on Chrome desktop:

```html
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var initESW = function (gslbBaseURL) {
        embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = true; //Or false
        embedded_svc.settings.language = 'en'; //For example, enter 'en' or 'en-US'
        embedded_svc.settings.enabledFeatures = ['LiveAgent'];
        embedded_svc.settings.entryFeature = 'LiveAgent';
        embedded_svc.init(
            'https://ulr.my.salesforce.com',
            'https://ulr.force.com/visualforce',
            gslbBaseURL,
            '00D7a00000055uj',
            'Products',
            {
                'baseLiveAgentContentURL': 'https://c.la3-c1cs-cdg.salesforceliveagent.com/content',
                'deploymentId': '720008Oqg',
                'buttonId': '5730PID',
                'baseLiveAgentURL': 'https://d.la3-c1cs-cdg.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',
                'eswLiveAgentDevName': 'EmbeddedServiceLiveAgent_Parent0000000jLUAQ_17d9a605e8e',
                'isOfflineSupportEnabled': false
            }
        );
    }
    initESW('https://service.force.com');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried doing it. I kept my html content on `run.mocky.io` and got an url. Now I am getting error `[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Message origin must match parent origin!", source: https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/eswFrame.min.js (7)`. I assigned you bounty even before trying this solution so that it wont go unused :). Please help me for this issue?

Comment: What happens if you use this URL in a regular desktop browser? Do you have a URL to share that I can inspect?

Comment: I've edited my answer with additional details.

Comment: When I use same file in w3school online html editor, I can see chat buttons coming up. Not sure why this error coming in mobile application. Above url in comment gives me that error. This is the url I am using https://run.mocky.io/v3/0093032c-1e40-4c0f-bba1-08241a4fed64

Comment: I've just loaded this URL in an Android webview and it works properly: `https://run.mocky.io/v3/b4625e05-9f46-4d93-b1c6-4f12066e931f`. It must be something with your webview config. Can you enable DomStorageEnabled  on your webview? Salesforce needs local storage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243228/discussion-between-jean-baptiste-martin-and-r15).

Comment: Hi, can you please have a look on my another question if you have idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71708368/webview-is-not-rendering-css-styles-with-loaddatawithbaseurl-only-loading-plain

Answer (score 0):

`getSessionData requires two non-null arguments`, meaning your `getSessionData(a,b)` function is getting `null` value for `a` or `b` or both of them.
Why is it getting `null`, there's something wrong in one of the previous functions which calls `getSessionsData()` function or you are actually running this function with `null` data in parameter.