# CSS Styles not getting loaded only plain HTML loading for Mobile and Chrome browser for Salesforce chat UI

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, salesforce

`Html` page content on being load `Webview` using `LoadDataWithBaseURL` and it displays a page which I need. In this page when I click a button, it takes me to second page. Only second page having problem, this is just displaying plain `html` controls, there is no `CSS`.

Left screenshot is coming and right one is expected

[image]

Below is the Webview sample code

```
Control.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient(this, $"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
Control.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
Control.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
Control.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
Control.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
Control.LoadDataWithBaseURL("https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js", content1, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

[here the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71484378/message-origin-must-match-parent-origin-error-javascript) loading on `Webview` initially which has `html` and `JavaScript`.

How can I fix this issue ?

Edit 1 : This is how I am trying to load `styles` inside `head tag` of above mentioned html content file. I tried many combination using `rel type` also. Nothing seem to be working.

```
//1
<base href="/">
<link href="file:///android_asset/salesforce-lightning-design-system_touch-demo.css" type="text/css"/>

//2
<base href="/">
<link href="salesforce-lightning-design-system_touch-demo.css" type="text/css"/>

//3
<base href="/">
<link href="file:///android_asset/salesforce-lightning-design-system_touch-demo.css" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" />


//4
<link href="salesforce-lightning-design-system_touch-demo.css" type="text/css" />

//5
<link href="/salesforce-lightning-design-system_touch-demo.css" type="text/css">

//6
<link href="file:///android_asset/salesforce-lightning-design-system_touch-demo.css" type="text/css"  />
```

When I tried `<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />`, its working in `chrome browser` but not working in mobile application.

Comment: I can't figure out how you're trying to load your styles

Comment: @ZachJensz - I have edited my question please check.

Comment: Use full CSS path in href="{SERVER URL}/salesforce-lightning-design-system_touch-demo.css"

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternative way by injecting css styles. I am proud to share an example usage with you. You can use it in Activity or fragment. Converting to Kotlin will be easy.

For Sample Java code

```
        mWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        
       mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        final Activity activity = this;
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
//                Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionRequest");
                // As we are targeting Android 21, there's no need to prompt for permission.
                // Just go ahead and grant the permission here.
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view,
                                        int errorCode,
                                        String description,
                                        String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
                // Ignore SSL certificate errors - DANGEROUS, JUST FOR NOW
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // Clear out speech hooks, etc. when the page is loaded
//                Log.i(TAG, "onPageStarted: Clearing user handlers!");
//                if (mSrec != null) mSrec.clearUserHandlers();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                injectCSS(); // TODO < YOUR INJECT CSS
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });

        mWebView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        layout.addView(mWebView, 0);
    }

    private void injectCSS() {
        try {
            mWebView.evaluateJavascript(
                "javascript:(function() {" +
                "   console.log('Injecting code');" +
                "   let style = document.createElement('style');" +
                "   style.type = 'text/css';" +

                "   style.innerHTML = '" +
                "   head {" +
                "       -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);" +
                "       transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);" +
                "   };" +
                "   body {" +
                "       -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);" +
                "       transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);" +
                "   };';" +

                "   document.head.appendChild(style);" +
                "   document.body.appendChild(style);" +
                "})()",
                null
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Or

SalesForce Documents

```
embedded_svc.settings.externalStyles = ["...", “...”]
```

Specify your resources using the static resource name, not the file name itself. For example, if you upload CustomEvent.css and give it the name CustomEventCSS, enter CustomEventCSS.

For Javascripts

```
embedded_svc.settings.externalScripts = ["...", “...”]
```

[Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_set_custom_events.htm)

Comment: I have tried externalStyles - `embedded_svc.settings.externalStyles = ['file:///android_asset/salesforce-lightning-design-system_touch-demo'];`. This is not making any difference.

Comment: I have more than one `.css` files in `assets` folder downloaded. How to use/mention those files in `injectCSS` methods ?

Comment: Use StringBuilder

StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
data .append("<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=\"mycss.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body>");
data .append(tables.toString());
data .append("</body></HTML>");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data .toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Comment: Thank you. I am already having one URL at first `param` in `loadDataWithBaseURL` and that is mandatory. How can I add another one ? If I remove existing URL app is not working.

Comment: Created custom HTML file sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508807/5595926

Comment: If you see my edit 1 in question, that is what I have been trying. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try loading CSS files like this or use internal css.

```
embedded_svc.settings.externalStyles = ["...", “...”]
```

Source [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_set_custom_events.htm)